# How can I access the variables of an inner class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

```
class outer{
  int c,

  void values() {
    inner.a=3;
    inner.b=4;
  }

  void addvalues() {
      **inner.a += c;** // **How can I access the value of a=3 from the values() method?**
  }

  class inner{
      int a,b;
  }
}
```

Comment: Which `inner` instance's?

Comment: @user3081058 I've done it for you this instance, but please, when you're asking for help, please take the time to properly format your code. No one will want to read a horrible dump of text.

Answer (score 3):

1) you need an instance of `inner` to do that

or

2) you can declare `inner` as `static` and make its variable `a` also static

Comment: If you're accessing the variables from the enclosing class, they don't need to be public.

Comment: That's correct. Or make `inner` and `a` both static.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an instance of the Inner class in the Outer class. Also, as you would with any other class definition, just use getters and setters of the inner class within the outer class. Something like this:

```
public class Outer {

    private int c;
    private Inner inner = new Inner();

    public void values() {
        inner.setA(3);
        inner.setB(4);
    }

    public void addValues()
    {
        inner.setA(inner.getA() + inner.getB());
    }

    public int getA() {
        return inner.getA();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Outer outer = new Outer();
        outer.values();
        outer.addValues();
        System.out.println(outer.getA());
    }

    class Inner {
        int a;
        int b;

        public int getA() {
            return a;
        }
        public int getB() {
            return b;
        }
        public void setA(int a) {
            this.a = a;
        }
        public void setB(int b) {
            this.b = b;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks alot, i think it will work